# TriggerUtils: How to make something trigger after a minute?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a Command that I want to trigger after lets say a minute. How will I be able to do that. As far as I understand, if I use makeMinutelyTrigger, it makes it trigger every minute, but the first trigger is immediate. I want the first trigger to be after a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a start time (startAt) to your trigger, the quartz [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05) has numerous examples